# US laws requiring US citizens to enter the country at designated border crossings

Tags: united-states, borders

I've been able to find only one law that requires people entering the US to use designated border crossing points, which is [8 USC 1325](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1325).  This law applies only to aliens, however; both relevant subsections of the code begin with "Any alien who...."

Is there a US law that requires US citizens to use designated ports of entry when entering the US?

Is there a law requiring US citizens to present themselves for immigration inspection (or customs inspection) if they cross the border somewhere other than a designated port of entry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes for individuals,](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/19/1459) and [yes for vehicles.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/19/1433) They're customs laws rather than immigration laws.