# Does someone in the U.S. illegally have the same rights in court as a U.S. citizen?

Tags: united-states, illegal-immigration, bill-of-rights

So right now in my home state of Iowa, an undocumented immigrant is on trial for murder charges. Apparently he wasn't read his rights when he was being investigated.

Whether that is true or not, does he have those same rights as a U.S. citizen?

Comment: If illegal immigrants didn't have the same rights as citizens it could imply that citizens themselves didn't have those rights since many of the legal action against immigrants is precisely about whether they're legitimate citizens or not.

Comment: @ShmuelNewmark: No, it would mean that courts would have to extend those rights to all until citizenship/immigration status is established.

Answer (score 55):

Everyone physically present in the US is protected by the US   Federal constitution. (In some cases persons not physically in the US also have protection from the US constitution. When that applies is too complex for this answer.) Most of the rights protected by that constitution are available to anyone present, whether citizen, lawful immigrant, lawful visitor, or a person in the US without lawful authority. A few rights, such as the right to vote and to run for public office, are limited to citizens.

If a person was arrested but not informed of his or her *Miranda* rights, then statements made to the arresting officers (or later interrogating officers) would not be admissible in court, unless an exception to the Miranda rules applies, which is unlikely. I can't say if this happened in the particular case mentioned in the question.

In general, in the area of criminal procedure, there is no difference between citizens and others subject to US jurisdiction (accredited foreign diplomats normally have immunity). A few crimes can only be committed by citizens (or others owing allegiance to the US) such as treason. A few crimes, such as unlawful entry to the US, can't be committed by citizens, as citizens automatically have a right to enter. But criminal procedure and constitutional rights affecting criminal procedure, are the same for all in the US, citizen or not. (Oh, there are special laws for minors, but that isn't a matter of citizenship.)

Comment: There are also crimes that can only be committed by foreigners, acts that are constitutional rights of Americans. E.g. Maria Butina.

Comment: @Keith McClary There are, as I mentioned, but  18 U.S.C. §951 (which is what Butina was convicted of)  is not one of them. A US citizen can be convicted of being an unregistered agent of a non-US government in the US.

Comment: I can't find an example of a conviction in comparable circumstances. Should I ask a Question?

Comment: @Keith McClary  sure, why not, it could be a good question.

Comment: I would need to ask about the law first. If she was hanging out with the Sierra Club instead of the NRA, and her Russian government contact was a schoolteacher or a postman instead of a banker, could she still be convicted?

Comment: @KeithMcClary Rudolph Giuliani is apparently under investigation for possible violations of 18 USC 951.

Comment: @KeithMcClary  Potentially, yes The question under  18 U.S.C. §951 is, did the accused act as an agent of a non-US government in the US without registering, and was the accused required to register under the regulations put out by the US Attorney General. It has nothign to do with hoew the accused received directions from the non-US govt, or how or thru what group those directions were carried out, or whether the govt was an ally of the US or not (although that might affect a decision to prosecute)..

Comment: @KeithMcClary a better example would be possession of firearms, which is a constitutional right for citizens (although subject to various conditions) yet illegal for certain categories of non-citizens.

Comment: Whenever rights are discussed, a discussion of the concept of natural rights is in order.

Comment: @paulj It is not relevant to this question, which is about the specific **legal** rights that non-citizens, and specifically those not lawfully in the country, have in the US, under US law.. Natural rights do not belong in such an answer, except as US law might reflect them. A separate question about them would be proper.

Comment: I'm not sure that last part is right.  A US citizen was arrested in Niagara Falls around June of 2020 for illegal entry after they tried to walk around inspection.

Comment: @rtaft  Interesting, Details would be helpful. I wonder if the actual charge was evading customs, or something of the sort. US Citizens do have to go through customs on entering the US, but have a protected right to enter. Can you give a link to a news story or other source on this?

Comment: @DavidSiegel https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/local-media-release/us-border-patrol-agents-arrest-us-citizen-illegal-entry

Comment: @DavidSiegel The headline calls it illegal entry, but the fine was for 19 USC §1459 which appears to be specific to crossing on foot at a non designated location and applies to everyone. 8 USC §1325b is similar but only specifies aliens.

Comment: @Rtaft note that the actual charge was [19 USC 1459](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/19/1459) which requires people to present themselves for customs inspection. illegal entry is [8 USC 1325](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1325), the text of which starts "Any alien who ... and so is on its face not applicable to a citizen.

Comment: Some people not physically present in the U.S. also have protection from the U.S. federal constitution when dealing with the United States government, although the law pertaining to when this is the case is rather complex.

Comment: @ohwilleke  Yes, thanks. I ah added a brief note on that to the answer.

Comment: @rtaft and David Siegel [US laws requiring US citizens to enter the country at designated border crossings](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/18164/333)

Answer (score 23):

> So right now in my home state of Iowa, an undocumented immigrant is on
> trial for murder charges. Apparently he wasn't read his rights when he
> was being investigated.
>
> Whether that is true or not, does he have those same rights as a U.S.
> citizen?

Most rights are not particular to U.S. citizens and apply to all persons regardless of their immigration status. The rights that apply without regard to immigration status include the [*Miranda v. Arizona*, 384 U.S. 436 (1966)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miranda_v._Arizona) rights of someone arrested and interrogated on suspicion of having committed a crime.

One [area of ongoing litigation](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/147630538.pdf) in regard to *Miranda* with non-citizens is the extent to which inquiries regarding immigration status (which is often, but not always, a civil matter) may be made without giving Miranda warnings.

Indeed, an undocumented immigrant, in addition to having a right to an attorney and notice of his or her right to an attorney, under *Miranda*, also has a right under an international treaty to assistance from a diplomatic official from the non-citizen's country of citizenship (as described in [this law review article](https://www.law.georgetown.edu/international-law-journal/wp-content/uploads/sites/21/2018/07/GT-GJIL180010.pdf)) under Article 36 of the [Vienna Convention on Consular Relations](https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/9_2_1963.pdf), a treaty ratified by the United States in 1969, although the U.S. has a poor track record of affording legal effect to this treaty right in practice [despite contrary ruling from the International Court of Justice](https://lawreview.syr.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/L-Babcock.pdf).

There are some rights, however, which are particular to U.S. citizens and are not shared by people who are not U.S. citizens. This includes, for example, the right to vote, and the right to enter the United States. The [right to bear arms is likewise more restricted for non-citizens](https://scholarship.law.uc.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1269&context=uclr) than it is for U.S. citizens, and non-citizens do not benefit from the right of U.S. citizens subject to some narrow exceptions, to not be discriminated against based upon state of primary residence. A [short note from a law professor at the University of Arkansas Law School](https://ualr.edu/socialchange/2020/11/16/undocumented-immigrants-have-constitutional-rights-too/) spells out in the case of a number of specific rights that do not depend upon citizenship.

> For instance, here is a non-exhaustive list of some rights
> undocumented immigrants may enjoy stemming from the United States
> Constitution:
>
> Right to jury trial;
>
> Right to Miranda warning;
>
> Right to defend against charges and deportation;
>
> Right to counsel in criminal proceedings;
>
> Right to protection from unlawful search and seizure;
>
> Right to protection against self-incrimination;
>
> Right to file civil lawsuits;
>
> Right to payment for work performed;
>
> Right to a healthy and safe work environment; and
>
> Right to k-12 education.

In general, outside of immigration law, U.S. law does not distinguish at all between the rights of documented and undocumented people who are not U.S. citizens, notwithstanding arguments by conservative legal scholars which have not been accepted by the courts that there should be a distinction between these two categories of people under non-immigration laws.

Answer (score 5):

For the most part, yes, and the other answers already elaborate on that better than I can.

I'll broaden the answer to your question from just the Miranda rights to other aspects of crime and punishment. There are a number of differences:

- Non-citizens are entitled to have a consulate of their home country notified, and provide assistance. Some US states are notorious for ignoring this obligation based on treaties, though. Incidentally, dual US/non-US citizens do not have this right.
- There are some crimes that citizens cannot commit in the first place.
- A conviction even for minor issues has far more severe subsequent consequences for a non-citizen than for a citizen. For instance, a DUI for a US citizen may lead to a loss of driver's license and a few weeks in prison. For a non-citizen (even those who have lived in the US legally for decades), it may mean deportation, destruction of their family, loss of their home and livelihood and ending up penniless in a country they may not even be familiar with.
- Non-citizens are often not eligible for bail or parole; they will usually have to serve out the full sentence in prison. Bail is usually denied based on the idea that they are an inherent flight risk, and parole is denied because they would be deported the day they are released, making supervision by a parole officer impossible.
- Many police departments will hold non-citizens past their release date without a warrant (even though that practice has been ruled unconstitutional before).

Comment: DUI alone is not grounds for deportation from the US. But if a person is already liable to deportation, then having a DUI conviction can affect their ability to obtain "cancellation of removal".

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not correct. DUI is considered a "crime of moral turpitude", and that often (not always) does make you deportable. A lot depends on the details, and also on the maximum sentence in your state.

Comment: Sorry, let me be more precise. "Simple DUI" is not a crime of moral turpitude. By "simple DUI" I mean a criminal offense where the only elements of the offense are driving, and being under the influence of alcohol. There are "aggravated DUI" offenses that can be crimes of moral turpitude. Since the vast majority of all DUI cases are simple DUI, I think you should edit your answer. Currently, your answer implies that DUI is *always* a crime of moral turpitude. See https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/eoir/legacy/2014/07/25/3423.pdf

Comment: @Brian You are right. I thought I had phrased it as a "may" but I didn't. It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out!